# VSTO vb.net excel with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, vsto

Part need to work on
I got almost everything working except for this VBA code as I am trying to translate to VB.net net but no success. I would even take C# samples.

```
       '.IconSetCondition.IconSet.IconSets = "xl3Triangles"
```

Original post
I am new to vb.net and VSTO and the documentation is not great for conditional formatting as I am modifying code from VBA to vb.net any ideas?

```
    With customerYearRng
        .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition()
        '.IconSetCondition.IconSet.IconSets = "xl3Triangles"
        '.FormatConditions(FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        '.FormatConditions(1)
        '.FormatConditions.ReverseOrder = False
        '.FormatConditions.ShowIconOnly = False
        '.FormatConditions.IconSet.IconSets = "xl3Triangles"
        '.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
        '.Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        '.Value = 0
        '.Operator = 7
        '.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
        '.Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        '.Value = 0
        '.Operator = 5
    End With
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing?  "documentation is not great" - the VBA docs are not bad, and should be translatable to vb.net

Comment: It is an issue with translating to vb.net as it seems not straight forward. I managed to get the Icon criteria working the way want as I used the range and with a combination of with statement and seeing how borders are applied in VB.net in VSTO , but the other methods I still have issues with.             '.FormatConditions(1)
        '.FormatConditions.ReverseOrder = False
        '.FormatConditions.ShowIconOnly = False
        '.FormatConditions.IconSet.IconSets = "xl3Triangles

Comment: I only have issues with IconSet as it seems not to cause a bug but nothing happens got the rest to work.   `.FormatConditions(1).IconSet = Excel.XlIconSet.xl3Arrows`  the vba is this            `'.IconSetCondition.IconSet.IconSets = "xl3Triangles"`

Comment: If you check my code below and also  - https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-apply-icon-set-conditional-formatting-with-vba-macro/ you can see that's not how IconSet is assigned (at least in VBA) - you assign it from the parent workbook's `IconSets`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB.NET or VSTO programmer, but the small amount of Excel automation I've done from .NET seemed a pretty straightforward translation from a working VBA implementation.

Your code can be easier to deal with if you take advantage of the fact that `AddIconSetCondition` returns the added condition, so you don't have to go looking for it in the range's `FormatConditions` collection.

Working VBA (which I think is close to what you're wanting to set up in VB.NET) -

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rng As Range, isc As IconSetCondition
    
    Set rng = Selection 'or whatever
    
    Set isc = rng.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition()
    
    isc.SetFirstPriority
    isc.IconSet = rng.Parent.Parent.IconSets(xl3Triangles)
    isc.ReverseOrder = False
    isc.ShowIconOnly = False
    
    With isc.IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 0
        .Operator = 7
    End With
    
    With isc.IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 0
        .Operator = 5
    End With
    
End Sub
```

EDIT: a simple working console app using VB.NET -

```vb
Imports xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xlApp As xl.Application
        Dim wb As xl.Workbook
        Dim rng As xl.Range
        Dim isc As xl.IconSetCondition

        xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        wb = xlApp.Workbooks("Book1")
        rng = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

        isc = rng.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition()

        isc.SetFirstPriority()
        isc.IconSet = wb.IconSets(xl.XlIconSet.xl3Triangles)
        isc.ReverseOrder = False
        isc.ShowIconOnly = False

        With isc.IconCriteria(2)
            .Type = xl.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 0
            .Operator = 7
        End With

        With isc.IconCriteria(3)
            .Type = xl.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 0
            .Operator = 5
        End With

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: VB.net does not support the set statement and for the range  Got this error System.MissingMemberException
  HResult=0x80131512
  Message=Public member 'IconSetCondition' on type 'Application' not found.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>          Will post sample modified code   to show

Comment: Sub Tester()
        Dim rng As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Sheets("Territory Summary").Range("B:B")
        Dim isc As Excel.IconSet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.IconSetCondition
        isc = rng.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition()
        isc.SetFirstPriority
        'isc.IconSet = rng.Parent.Parent.IconSets.(xl3Triangles)
        isc.IconSet = Excel.XlIconSet.xl3Arrows
        isc.ReverseOrder = False
        isc.ShowIconOnly = False


    End Sub

Comment: This would be easier to read as an edit to your original post...